# How to SUM multiple column with multiple conditions and show in one

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table like this , Now I need to get all data GROUP BY tpi

```
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
| trxDate             | trxType | tpi            |
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
| 2018-06-28 00:00:00 | Sent    | SI0005         |
| 2018-07-02 00:00:00 | Sent    | SI0005         |
| 2018-07-04 00:00:00 | Sent    | SI0005         |
| 2018-05-25 00:00:00 | Open    | SI0007         |
| 2018-06-26 00:00:00 | Open    | SI0007         |
| 2018-05-25 00:00:00 | Sent    | SI0007         |
| 2018-06-23 00:00:00 | Sent    | SI0007         |
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
```

I need records to sum open and sent

```
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
| tpi                 | open    | sent           |
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
|  SI0005             | 0       | 3              |
|  SI0007             | 2       | 2              |   
+---------------------+---------+----------------+
```

I have tried with some subquery but not getting desired response

```
SELECT  tblcount.tpi, tblcount.qType, count(tblcount.id) total FROM (SELECT id, tpi, 'Open' qType FROM `tbl`WHERE trxType = 'Open' UNION SELECT id, tpi, 'Sent' qType FROM `tbl` WHERE trxType = 'Sent') tblcount GROUP BY  tblcount.third_party_id, tblcount.qType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select tpi,
       sum( (trx_type = 'open') ) as num_open,
       sum( (trx_type = 'sent') ) as num_sent
from tbl
group by tpi;
```

This uses a MySQL extension that treats a boolean expression as an integer in an integer context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score 1):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select tpi,
       sum(trxType = 'Open') as trxType_open, 
       sum(trxType = 'Sent') as trxType_Sent
from tbl t
group by tpi;
```